# Why cgroup cpu items are miss in Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, cgroups

the kernel version for debian 8 use 3.10. But under /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu, miss a lot of cpu items.

```
vagrant@debian-jessie:/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu$ ls -1 .
cgroup.clone_children
cgroup.procs
cgroup.sane_behavior
cpuacct.stat
cpuacct.usage
cpuacct.usage_percpu
cpu.shares
notify_on_release
release_agent
tasks
```

How do I enable `cpu.cfs_quota_us` in debian 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recompile your kernel with `CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH=y`.
There is a [feature request](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=789019) about this already.

Comment: how about kernel 4 from backports do you have any idea if it supports cgroups?

Comment: Cgroup support is present in all recent Debian Linux kernels (it's required for systemd). However, I couldn't find any trace of `CFS_BANDWIDTH` being enabled in the SVN trunk of the kernel package. And it would be noted in the linked bug report, too.

Comment: Interesting. How does it affects docker deployments?

Comment: No personal experience, but the [upstream docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/debian/) imply that it's OK. [Others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704722/how-do-i-install-docker-on-an-nvidia-tegra-jetson-tk1-with-a-32-bit-arm-processo) seem to regard it a problem, though.

Answer (score 3):

I purchased the cgroup extension today (Plesk add on extension)  and only found out that it did not support debian 8.7 with default kernel afterwards.

I manage a dedicated server hosted at Hetzner.
Debian 8.6 Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64

Only option I had available on the server after install the extension was a way to control disk usage.

Making this change in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

Did not solve the issue

Output of the command:

```
 plesk sbin resctrl --features
 {"cpu": false, "cpuacct": true, "memory": true, "blkio": true, "vhosts_blkio": false}
```

Web interface only show the option for disk usage.

**This is what worked in the end:**

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

reboot

After rebooting the system the out put of the command

```
plesk sbin resctrl --features
{"cpu": true, "cpuacct": true, "memory": true, "blkio": true, "vhosts_blkio": false}
```

Reinstall Plesk extension...